# checkout subfolder of repo with bower

Tags: git, bower

i need to checkout a certain subfolder of a git repository with bower.

It is a repository holding a lot of PHP Sources and Build files and i only need a certain subfolder.

Problem is, i also need to make sure the bower deps of that subfolder (*stored in a bower.json in said subfolder*) are taken into concern.

Also, i can not use sub repositories!

Any Ideas?

So far i would use the `ignore` feature for [bower.json](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#bowerjson) files and put the `bower.json` in the Root of the repo. That is not ideal because then my deps are in `"Source/Resources/js/"` and i (*and my co-contributers*) always need to add every new folder in `Source` to said ignore list.

Ideal would be to have the opposite of ignore, a "*I want these files and folders*" rather than "*i do not want these and those*".